# Salesforce - Process variable number of form fields

Tags: forms, salesforce, apex-code

I've been able to do this in PHP but it's not translating to Salesforce very well.

I have a form to input an Opportunity. It has an Account, a Contact, and a variable number of fields that will be used to create custom objects (For my purposes an Opportunity is a trip, and the custom objects are legs of that trip). The Salesforce controller needs to create a new Opportunity with the Account and Contact (that's the easy part) but then it needs to create a new custom object (Leg__c) for each leg of the trip.

My form looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Account" />
<input type="text" name="Contact" />
<div id="leg0">
  <input type="text" name="dep[0]" />
  <input type="text" name="arr[0]" />
</div>
<div id="leg1">
  <input type="text" name="dep[1]" />
  <input type="text" name="arr[1]" />
</div>
...
```

I'm not even sure where to begin on this one...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how many legs you need, you can simply create a list of them in your visualforce controller:

```
public list<Leg__c> liLegs {get; set;};

// upon oppty creation:
liLegs = new list<Leg__c>();

for (integer i = 0; i < iNumLegs; i++)
{
    liLegs.add(new Leg__c());
}
```

Then you can just loop over these in your page like so:

```
<apex:repeat var="v" value="{!liLegs}">
    <apex:inputField value="{!v.Dep__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!v.Arr__c}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

The input fields will correspond to the fields in each entry in the list, so then in your Save action or whatever you're using you can just insert the list `insert liLegs;`.

Hope this is of help and I haven't missed the mark, let me know if so! PS. I've just written this code directly in here so it may not be 100% syntactically correct ;)

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but my number of legs is variable (I'm using jQuery to add more legs on demand).

Comment: Ah, that makes things somewhat more tricky. In situations like that my solution has always been to just pass the values of my new fields back to the controller using a parameter, building up a semi-colon delimited list or similar.